# Optimization of code

Tags: performance-tuning

I have written a following mathematica code which involve solution to nonlinear equations. It produce results according to my expectation but it take more than a day in execution which is very annoying. I am not expert in coding but I think my way of solving is inefficient. Can somebody help me what should I change to speedup the execution time without effecting the final results. By the way, I am using mathematica 11.3 on dell core i5, 4 GB ram machine.

````
1/0 // Quiet; 
α = 2.3026*(10^-3);
rho = 2.2*10^-12;
MFD = 4.2;
w0 = MFD/2;
R = List[8, 6, 4, 2, 1];
T0c = 25;
T0 = 25 + 273.15;
surrho = 1.184;  
surμ = 1.837*10^-5; 
surυ = 1.552*10^-5;  
surCp = 1.006*10^3; 
surKK = 0.02624;          
surg = 9.8;                   
 surβ = 3380*10^-6;
Array[TStack, 5];
For[x = 1, x < 6, x++,
 If[R[[x]] > MFD, Rp = MFD, Rp = R[[x]]]; 
  S0 = -(2/(Pi*(2.1*10^-6)^2))*((3.998*10^3)/(Exp[-(2*((62.5/
               w0)^2))] - 1));
 
 S = S0*Exp[-2*(r*R[[x]]/w0)^2]; 
 A0 = α*S*10^-18;
 
 surR   = R[[x]]*10^-6;        
 surκ = 
  surKK/(surCp*
     surrho);                                                         \
                                                      
 Pr = 0.71; 
 Tc = T0 + 0.000000002; 
 TcNew = Tc + 0.000000001;
 While[Abs[(((TcNew - Tc)/Tc)*100)] > 10^-10, Print["Tc"]; 
  Print[N[Tc, 25]]; Print["TcNew"]; Print[N[TcNew, 25]]; Tc = TcNew;
  Tf = (Tc + T0)/2;
  Gr = 8*surg*(surR^3)*(surυ ^-2)*(1/Tf)*(Tc - T0); 
  Print["Gr"]; Print[Gr];  
   Nu1 = (0.6 + ((0.387*((Gr*Pr)^(1/
              6)))/((1 + ((0.559/Pr)^(9/16)))^(8/27))))^2 ;
  Hc = (1/2)*Nu1*surKK*(1/surR); Print["Hc"]; Print[Hc];
  ξ = 0.85; 
  σ = 5.669*10^-8;
  Hr = (ξ*σ*((Tc^4) - (T0^4)))/(Tc - T0); 
  H = Hc + Hr; 
  H = H*10^-12 ;
  KK = (2.14749 - (298.76*Tc^(-1)) + ((20.72*10^3)*
        Tc^(-2)) - ((0.54*10^6)*Tc^-3))*10^-6;
  Cp = (1/
      60.0843)*(55.98 + ((15.40*10^(-13))*Tc) - ((14.4*10^(-5))*
        Tc^(-2)));
  κ = KK/(rho*Cp); 
  τ := κ*t;
  B0 = A0/KK ;
  h = (H/KK);
  val = (αn*R[[x]])*BesselJ[1, αn*R[[x]]] - (h*R[[x]])*
     BesselJ[0, αn*R[[x]]];
  roots = Solve[val == 0 && 0 < αn < 1, αn][[All, 1, 2]];
  Print["roots"];
  Print[roots];
  
  cn = ((2/(Rp^2))*(1/((BesselJ[
             0, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]^2) + (BesselJ[
             1, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]^2))))^0.5;  
  b1 = 2/((w0*roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]])^2);  
  dn = Abs[
    B0*cn*((w0/
         2)^2)*(((BesselJ[0, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]*
           Exp[-2*((Rp/w0)^2)]) - 1) + 
       Sum[(((-1)^l)/((2^(l + 1))*(l!)*Gamma[l + 2]))*((Gamma[l + 1] -
              Gamma[l + 1, 
              b1*((roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)^2)])/(2*(b1^(l + 
                 1)))), {l, 0, Infinity}])]; 
  Tn = (dn/(roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]^2))*(1 - 
      Exp[-(roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]^2)*τ]);
  u1 = T0c + (Sum[
       Tn[[i]]*cn[[i]]*BesselJ[0, (roots[[i]]*(R[[x]]*r))], {i, 1, 
        Length[roots]}]) /. t -> Infinity; Print["u1="]; Print[u1]; 
  Print["u1 at r=0"]; Print[N[u1 /. r -> 0]]; 
  Print["u1 at r=R[[x]]"]; Print[N[u1 /. r -> 1]]; 
  TcNew = N[(u1 /. r -> 1 )] + 273.15; Print["Tc="]; Print[Tc]; 
  Print["TcNew="]; Print[TcNew]];
 Print["Heat Transfer Co-efficient = "]; Print[H];
 TStack[x] = u1; Print["x"]; Print[x]; 
 Print[TStack[x]]]; Print["TStack"]; Print[TStack[1]];
Plot[{TStack[1], TStack[2], TStack[3], TStack[4], TStack[5]}, {r, 0, 
  1}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, Axes -> {True, True},
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontWeight -> Plain, 
   FontFamily -> Helvetica}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[(Style[#, 22, Plain, 
        FontFamily -> Helvetica] &) /@ {"R=8 [μm]", 
      "R=6 [μm]", "R=4 [μm]", "R=2 [μm]", "R=1 [μm]"},
     LegendMarkerSize -> 50, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 3}], {0.7, 0.6}],
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 25}, AxesStyle -> Dashed, 
 FrameLabel -> {"r/R (Normalized Radius)", 
   "T \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(o\)]\)C]"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Orange, Thick}, {Dashed, Red, 
    Thick}, {Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.025, 0.01}], Purple, 
    Thick}, {Black, Dashing[{Large}], Thick}, {Blue, Dashing[Tiny], 
    Thick}}, ImageSize -> 700, Filling -> Axis]
```
````

Comment: Are all of these lines of code really necessary to produce a **minimal working example** of the problem you are facing? Remember that this is a Q&A site, not a free code-improving service :)

Comment: Maybe you could also post the mathematical form of your equations in LaTeX?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer you are right but as I explained in my question the code produces result as expected but it takes very long execution time and I don't know which part of my code is inefficient. By the way I will work on it to produce a **minimal working example** having the same  problem.

Comment: A good start would be to find which parts/lines/commands/functions in the code take a long time to run. You can use Timing[ ] or AbsoluteTiming[ ] to help spot the slow areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every line of code where `u1` and `TStack` are using as output we need to add option `/.Infinity -> 50` (we can play with it by using less then 50 or more then 50). With this option your code run few second on my machine:

```
α = 2.3026*(10^-3);
rho = 2.2*10^-12;
MFD = 4.2;
w0 = MFD/2;
R = List[8, 6, 4, 2, 1];
T0c = 25;
T0 = 25 + 273.15;
surrho = 1.184;
surμ = 1.837*10^-5;
surυ = 1.552*10^-5;
surCp = 1.006*10^3;
surKK = 0.02624;
surg = 9.8;
surβ = 3380*10^-6;
Array[TStack, 5];

For[x = 1, x < 6, x++, If[R[[x]] > MFD, Rp = MFD, Rp = R[[x]]];
  S0 = -(2/(Pi*(2.1*10^-6)^2))*((3.998*10^3)/(Exp[-(2*((62.5/
                w0)^2))] - 1));
  S = S0*Exp[-2*(r*R[[x]]/w0)^2];
  A0 = α*S*10^-18;
  surR = R[[x]]*10^-6;
  surκ = surKK/(surCp*surrho);
  Pr = 0.71;
  Tc = T0 + 0.000000002;
  TcNew = Tc + 0.000000001;
  While[Abs[(((TcNew - Tc)/Tc)*100)] > 10^-10, Print["Tc"];
   Print[N[Tc, 25]]; Print["TcNew"]; Print[N[TcNew, 25]]; Tc = TcNew;
   Tf = (Tc + T0)/2;
   Gr = 8*surg*(surR^3)*(surυ^-2)*(1/Tf)*(Tc - T0);
   Print["Gr"]; Print[Gr];
   Nu1 = (0.6 + ((0.387*((Gr*Pr)^(1/
               6)))/((1 + ((0.559/Pr)^(9/16)))^(8/27))))^2;
   Hc = (1/2)*Nu1*surKK*(1/surR); Print["Hc"]; Print[Hc];
   ξ = 0.85;
   σ = 5.669*10^-8;
   Hr = (ξ*σ*((Tc^4) - (T0^4)))/(Tc - T0);
   H = Hc + Hr;
   H = H*10^-12;
   KK = (2.14749 - (298.76*Tc^(-1)) + ((20.72*10^3)*
         Tc^(-2)) - ((0.54*10^6)*Tc^-3))*10^-6;
   Cp = (1/
       60.0843)*(55.98 + ((15.40*10^(-13))*Tc) - ((14.4*10^(-5))*
         Tc^(-2)));
   κ = KK/(rho*Cp);
   τ := κ*t;
   B0 = A0/KK;
   h = (H/KK);
   val = (αn*R[[x]])*BesselJ[1, αn*R[[x]]] - (h*R[[x]])*
      BesselJ[0, αn*R[[x]]];
   roots = 
    NSolve[val == 0 && 0 < αn < 1, αn][[All, 1, 2]];
   Print["roots"];
   Print[roots];
   cn = ((2/(Rp^2))*(1/((BesselJ[
              0, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]^2) + (BesselJ[
              1, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]^2))))^0.5;
   b1 = 2/((w0*roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]])^2);
   dn = Abs[
     B0*cn*((w0/
          2)^2)*(((BesselJ[0, (roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)]*
            Exp[-2*((Rp/w0)^2)]) - 1) + 
        Sum[(((-1)^l)/((2^(l + 1))*(l!)*
              Gamma[l + 2]))*((Gamma[l + 1] - 
              Gamma[l + 1, 
               b1*((roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]*Rp)^2)])/(2*(b1^(l + 
                  1)))), {l, 0, Infinity}])];
   Tn = (dn/(roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]^2))*(1 - 
       Exp[-(roots[[1 ;; Length[roots]]]^2)*τ]);
   u1 = T0c + (Sum[
        Tn[[i]]*cn[[i]]*BesselJ[0, (roots[[i]]*(R[[x]]*r))], {i, 1, 
         Length[roots]}]) /. t -> Infinity; Print["u1="]; Print[u1];
   Print["u1 at r=0"]; Print[N[u1 /. {r -> 0, Infinity -> 50}]];
   Print["u1 at r=R[[x]]"]; Print[N[u1 /. {r -> 1, Infinity -> 50}]]; 
   TcNew = N[(u1 /. {r -> 1, Infinity -> 50})] + 273.15; Print["Tc="];
    Print[Tc];
   Print["TcNew="]; Print[TcNew]]; 
  Print["Heat Transfer Co-efficient = "]; Print[H];
  TStack[x] = u1; Print["x"]; Print[x];
  Print[TStack[x]]];

Print["TStack"]; Print[TStack[1] /. Infinity -> 50];
Plot[Evaluate[{TStack[1], TStack[2], TStack[3], TStack[4], 
TStack[5]} /. Infinity -> 50], {r, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 


PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}, Axes -> {True, True}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 22, FontWeight -> Plain, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"R=8 [μm]", "R=6 [μm]", "R=4 [μm]", 
   "R=2 [μm]", "R=1 [μm]"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 25}, 
 AxesStyle -> Dashed, 
 FrameLabel -> {"r/R (Normalized Radius)", 
   "T \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\([\), \(o\)]\)C]"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Orange, Thick}, {Dashed, Red, 
    Thick}, {Dashing[{0.025, 0.01, 0.025, 0.01}], Purple, 
    Thick}, {Black, Dashing[{Large}], Thick}, {Blue, Dashing[Tiny], 
    Thick}}, ImageSize -> 700, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thank You Alex. You just made my day.

Comment: @UbaidUllah You are welcome!